# magento 2.1.8 EE upgrade error

Tags: magento2.3.1, magento-2.1.8, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade magento version from 2.1.8 EE to magento version 2.3.1. 
I am trying to update using command line procedure given here

> [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apxm6.png)

At the step of Modify the Magento updater

I am getting the following error - 
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package magento/project-enterprise-edition with version 2.3.
  0.

[image]

I also tried to upgrade through script. 
It successfully upgraded from magento 2.1.8 EE to magento 2.3.1 EE through script on local setup , but not upgrading on server . 
The command to run the script just terminates showing no error on server instance.

Comment: composer install work ??

Comment: Yess composer install did work.